# An extension of representation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A,~B$ be two C*-algebras, if $A$ is an ideal in $B$, then do we have that any representation of $A$ can extend to a representation of $B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Let $\pi:A\to B(H)$ is a representation. We can assume that $\overline{\pi(A)H}=H$ (otherwise, we replace $H$ with $\overline{\pi(A)H}$).

Now you can define $\tilde\pi:B\to B(H)$ on the dense subspace $\pi(A)H$ by 
$$
\tilde\pi(b)\,\pi(a)\xi=\pi(ba)\xi.
$$
This is well-defined: if $\pi(a)\xi=\pi(a')\xi$, then $\pi(a-a')\xi=0$, and 
\begin{align}
\|\pi(b(a-a'))\xi\|^2&=\langle \pi(b(a-a'))\xi,\pi(b(a-a'))\xi\rangle
=\langle \pi((a-a')^*b^*)\pi(b(a-a'))\xi,\xi\rangle\\
&=\langle \pi((a-a')^*b^*b(a-a'))\xi,\xi\rangle\leq\|b\|^2\,
\langle \pi((a-a')^*(a-a'))\xi,\xi\rangle\\
&=\|b\|^2\,\|\pi(a-a')\xi\|^2=0.
\end{align}
So $\pi(ba)\xi=\pi(ba')\xi$.

The same estimates above show that $\tilde\pi$ is bounded.

It is elementary to check that $\tilde\pi$ is a representation.

Comment: Oh, yes, but you assume that $\pi$ is a non-degenerate representation. If not, why we can still replace $H$ with $\bar{ \pi(A)H }$?

Comment: I'm not assuming anything. The algebra $\pi(A)$ only acts on $\overline{\pi(A)H}$, it doesn't touch its orthogonal. You can change my argument and instead of saying that you replace $H$, just define $\tilde\pi(b)$ as I did on $\overline{\pi(A)H}$ and as zero on $(\pi(A)H)^\perp$.

Comment: I think you are right. It is too late, I need to sleep now. Night.